# How do I add external stylesheets to Plotly Dash after creating the app

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

When using a Dash runtime, which already provides the app variable (`dash.Dash`), you cant provide external stylesheets on creation like this:

```py
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash
# Dash version: 2.0.0

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
```

How do I add external stylesheets to Dash after creating the app (`dash.Dash`)?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access the non-documented property of the class and set it:

```py
app.config.external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP]
```